# How to print integer value from assembly code in C

Tags: c, assembly, 6502

I have written a function in 6502 assembly that calculates fibonacci number. I am invoking that function in C and then compiling both files into single binary file for 6502. But the output I get is different. The fibonacci of 10 is 55, but it outputs 2649. It calculates fibonacci of the number but not of integer between range of 0 to 10. For example fibonacci of 0 is 257, for 1 it is 258, and for 10 it is 2649 and so on. Why am I getting such output.

My C code: "main.c"

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fib();

int main() {
  unsigned int p = fib();
  printf("%u\n",p);
  return 0;
}
```

Where fib() is the external function in 6502 assembly, it is linked together with C code.

My 6502 code: "fib.s"

```
 fib:
    //calculates fibonacci
```

And I compile both the files using `cl65 -t sim6502 main.c fib.s -o fib`

Comment: 1. Use `extern` to mark externally defined functions in C.
2. Please post the assembly code too.
3. Try `uint8_t` instead of `unsigned int`

Comment: `extern` is unnecessary for function declarations (won't hurt though). You could just post assembly code which returns 42 for MCVE purposes. `fib()` seems to return `int`, you assign it to `unsigned int`. While it's probably fine here (at least it's not UB this way), you should probably use the same type.

Comment: If your 6502 is a C=64, and the basic rom is enabled, there is a routine to write an integer at $BDCD. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.sys.cbm/htHknwABEmg/KnAjH8FTQwwJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You left out the code for `fib.s`.

Most likely the compiler expecting a 16-bit return value, and you're leaving garbage (or the previous Fibonacci number) in the upper 8 bits (another register).  Print at `%#x` to make that more obvious (`0xhilo`), instead of the `256*hi + lo` that you're getting with unsigned decimal.

C requires `int` to be at least 16 bits, so declaring the return-type as `int` definitely tells the compiler that two 6502 register have meaningful values.

Declare the return value as `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` if your function only returns an 8-bit integer in one 6502 register.

Otherwise fix your asm to return 16-bit `int`.  (Check the compiler-generated asm to learn which registers are used by the calling convention.  I don't know 6502 personally, just that it has 8-bit registers.)

Comment: @MilapJhumkhawala Just be aware that with uint8_t, you won't be able to calculate more than the first 12 fibonacci numbers as already 13th does not fit any more into 8 bits...